# javascript file download

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to download a file (test.xml) and allow/prompt user to save the file on click on download button. The file resides in url "http://localhost/test/test.xml" .

I have added html code

```
<input type=button value="Download" onclick='javascript:download()/>
```

and javascript code is

```
function download() {
   var url = "http://localhost/test/test.xml";
       window.open(url, 'Download');
}
```

But this opens the page in new window. How do I prompt to download and save the file. Any inputs will be of help. Thanks

Comment: and i wonder, you tagged java for this question?

Comment: He maybe just don't know java and javascirpt if different.

Comment: @LastStar007 If you believe the [Java] tag is erroneous, you should *propose an edit*.  Downvoting for mistagging is ***completely inappropriate***. If you believe that the user is deliberately and repeatedly mistagging his questions (e.g. for greater visibility or general vandalism) then you should flag the question for moderator attention. Downvotes and upvotes should deal directly with the quality of the question.

Comment: Or maybe he tagged `java` because he's using `java` server-side based on previous questions by him. Since this question may require server-side code to fix, I think `java` is an appropriate tag.

Comment: It's actully something that needs to be done on server side so Java maybe isn't so wrong ;-)

Comment: are you using apache + php for the backend?

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the content type in the header. You need to do some server scripting or configurate your webserver.

I Googled a link that will help you in the right direction: http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/forcedownload.html

Comment: You can set headers on an XHR... Is there anything that can be done with that?

Comment: XHR helps you modify request, what I know you have to change the Content-type header in the response.

Answer (score 2):

Using you inital code, if you have access to the backend, when the xml is requested, add the following header with it:

```
Content-disposition: attachment; filename=test.xml;
```

Another route would be to use xmlhttprequest to get the file, then use a flash plugin to save it. I've used this method a bit, and the flash swf can be found [here](https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify)

Answer (score 0):

set the content type for the response header of the xml to be `application/xml`

Answer (score -1):

html:

```
<input id="downloadthis" value="Download"/>
```

inside javascript tag:

```
  $('#downloadthis').click( function() {
window.location.href = 'http://localhost/test/test.xml';
 } );
```

REF: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4864264/405117

Comment: It's wrong it will not show the Save as dialog. Read the post you are refering too.